# Mssql. Игнорировать ошибки в триггере

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Добрый день. Нужно реализовать реал-тайм запись с одной таблицы в таблицу другой базы. Смотрел в сторону репликации, на насколько я понял она работает только про графику. Остановился на создании триггера. Но... есть один недостаток. Я не смог добится того, если база приемник недоступна чтобы в приложении которое делает INSERT не возникало ошибки. Подскажите каие есть варианты?

Comment: Обернуть в try-catch? Но я бы не делал это в триггере - уж больно тяжко будет базе, особенно с кросс-запросами. Посмотрите на Service Broker.

Comment: try-catch не работает в триггере.

Comment: Работает: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b19c3c/1

Answer (score 1):

Написанное ниже работает SQL Server !!!

Предлагаю рассмотреть продукт [Oracle GoldenGate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/ru/middleware/goldengate/index.html).
Он осуществляет репликацию между разными базами данных, в том числе поддерживает MsSql.
Работает за счет захвата изменений из логов транзакций баз данных в режиме онлайн. Скачать дистрибутивы можно свободно с сайта Oracle.

Один компонент отвечает собственно за захват данных.

Второй компонент может эти данные пересылать по сети на другие сервера, справляясь со своей задачей даже при неустойчивой связи. И может эти данные рассылать сразу на несколько приемников, т.е. если надо их распространить на несколько серверов.

И третий компонент применяет изменения в другой базе данных. Причем при желании можно писать данные в таблицы с другой структурой, правда для таких случаев скорее всего придется писать ему SQL-запросы с помощью которых это делать.

Ну с настройками конечно не все раз и готово, но за пару дней вполне можно вкурить в поднятие его сервисов, генерацию описаний захватываемых данных (он может чуть ли ни конкретные записи по условиям только реплицировать), настройку пересыльщика и сервис применения изменений.

Статья по использованию совместно с MsSql [Использование Oracle GoldenGate 11g для репликации Microsoft SQL Server Database](http://www.oraclegis.com/blog/?p=2489)

Comment: При чем тут Oracle? речь о MsSQL

Comment: Эмм ... зачем минусуете. это не рекламма, продукт во первых для части применений бесплатен, во вторых я просто сам им пользовался и он отлично справляется

Comment: @Dmitry Это продукт корпорации Oracle, но как я написал выше, он работает с разными базами данных. Я лично реплицировал с помощью него данные на Mysql !!!. И для его работы присутствие Oracle Database не требуется

Comment: Зачем так упирать на то, что продукт поддерживает MySql, если вопрос о MsSQL?

Comment: для MSSQL не требуются продукты корпорации Oracle, он самодостаточен.

Comment: @Zufir Я просто предложил решение задачи. Первой строкой вопроса стоит "Нужно реализовать реал-тайм запись с одной таблицы в таблицу другой базы". Вот с помощью него можно это решить не создавая доп. нагрузку на сам mysql

Comment: @Dmitry Я понимаю, что можно и средствами mysql это реализовывать. Но иногда стоит посмотреть шире

Comment: @Mike, еще раз. Вопрос не по MySql, который бывший продукт компании Sun, а ныне продукт компании Oracle. Вопрос по MS Sql Server, что следует из тэгов. Решение может и хорошее. Но не по теме вопроса.

Comment: @Mike, при чем тут MySQL вообще? речь об MSSQL о взрослой базе, а не о детской поделке. MSSQL самодостаточен

Comment: Блин, вот этого я не заметил ... :) НО он поддерживает и MS SQL !!!

Comment: @Mike то-есть мои слова о самодостаточности MSSQL вас не убедили? Ему не нужен продукт от Oracle, у него своего инструментария вполне хватает

Comment: @Dmitry Я думаю тогда стоит написать ответ как решить эту задачу средствами MSSql. Я отлично понимаю, что у него обязаны быть свои средстве репликации, по крайней мере с Sybase одну из версий которого потом MS купила и сделала из него свой сервер я работал. Но человек почему то решил писать триггера, значит обычной репликации ему не достаточно. Я предложил необычную репликацию :)